# Double for cycle vba excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have been coding in VBA for excel but have not been able to get it to work.... I want to copy the cells from Sheet1 to the cells in some other sheets, with different cells in each sheet I need to copy to.

```
Sub copy()
 For i=2 To 4
  For k=0 To 10 Step 5
   Sheets("1").Cells((2+i,1),(6+i;12)).Copy Destination:=Sheets(i).Range("A2:L6")
  Next k
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: For starters, you don't have a `k` within your loop.

Comment: Get rid of the for k loop. Also don't add i to the cell reference if you don't want the reference to change.

Comment: You need to rework your question, and be specific.  What are you trying to get as a final result, and what problem you are having.  Could make some guesses based on K Step 5, etc. but it will be much easier to assist if you ask a direct question, and if possible, provide examples... such as "I'm trying to copy a block of cells from (4,1) through (8,12) from sheet 1 of a workbook to sheet 2,3,and 4 of the same workbook" etc.

Comment: `Sheets("1").Cells((2+i,1),(6+i;12)).Copy` should be closer to  `Sheets("1").Range(Sheets("1").Cells((2+i, 1),Sheets("1").Cells(6+i, 12)).Copy` . I have no idea what *k* does in all this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying and pasting, just set one range equal to the other, like so

```
Sub copy()
For i = 2 To 4
    Sheets(i).Range(Sheets(i).Cells(2+i,1), Sheets(i).Cells(6+i,12)) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:L6")
Next i
End Sub
```

Also, I removed the inner loop as `k` isn't being utilized and you had a semi-colon where I assume you meant to have a comma. And it's tough to tell what you are trying to accomplish exactly as you will be changing the rows you place the data on each sheet with your loop. So perhaps you don't want `i` in your cell reference. In that case, try going with

```
Sub copy()
For i = 2 To 4
    Sheets(i).Range("A2:L6") = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:L6")
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jeeped Also a good point. I guess instead I should say that the data will go in different places on each spreadsheet.

Comment: @Jeeped You are right to make sure that only correct answers are posted and I'm grateful you are sticking with me. You are right about this. I am typing too fast to get an answer out quickly and am paying for it, along with making you pay for it. I'll correct the issue with an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to copy cells A2:L6 on sheet1 to A2:L6 on sheet2, A7:L11 on sheet1 to A2:L6 on sheet3 and A12:L16 on sheet1 to A2:L6 on sheet4, then this should do it:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:L6").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:L6").Value
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:L6").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7:L11").Value
Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:L6").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A12:L16").Value
```

or if you prefer using a loop to allow it to be extended to Sheet5 and beyond:

```
For i = 2 To 4
    Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Range("A2:L6").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells((i - 2) * 5 + 2, 1), Cells((i - 2) * 5 + 7, 12)).Value
Next i
```

Note that there is still no need for a 'k'.